# a variable in the function on window.onload is not set properly

Tags: javascript, onload

When I coded like below, variable 'name' does not have a initial value "test".
This is working fine when I do not use "window.onload".

Is there any difference for javascript variables between with "window.onload" and without it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
      <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <!-- Start your code here -->

     <script>

     window.onload=function(){ 
     var name = "test";

     function foo(msg,msg2) {

              console.log(msg + '  ' + msg2);

              alert(this.name);

  }

  foo('normal call','default');

  var obj = {
              name : 'steve'
          }

  foo.call(obj,'call function','object'); 
  foo.apply(obj,['apply function','object']); 

   }


  </script>
  <!-- End your code here -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: use a debugger, examine `this` inside `foo` in all versions. the answer is there

Answer (score 0):

> This is working fine when I do not use "window.onload".

That's because when you're not putting that code in a function, you're declaring `name` at global scope, making it a global variable, and so you can access it as a property on the global object. In loose mode, when you call `foo` directly as in your first example, `this` inside `foo` will refer to the global object. And so outside the function, it works, because `name` is global.

Inside, it's just a normal variable, and there's no connection between that *variable* and any object you can get a reference to in your code.

Comment: Oh thank you. this is not a onload issue.